# Group by and show specific row value

Tags: php

> I have this code to output the value in table i used group by to
>   group the same item code but serial does not show it only show
>   onevalue the 123321.  The output should be 123321,4354

```
$invoicequery=mysqli_query($link,"Select SUM(INVOICE_ITEM_QTY_MX),INVOICE_ID_MX,INVOICE_ITEM_UPRICE_MX,INVOICE_ITEM_AMOUNT_MX,INVOICE_ITEM_SERIAL_MX,INVOICE_ITEM_DESC_MX,INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX from invoice WHERE BRANCH_CODE_MX='".$display_branchcode."' 
                                and INVOICE_NO_MX='".$invoicecode."' GROUP BY INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($invoicequery))
                                {
                                    $invoiceid=$row["INVOICE_ID_MX"];
                                    $itemcode=$row["INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX"];
                                    $itemquantity=$row['SUM(INVOICE_ITEM_QTY_MX)'];
                                    $unitprice=$row["INVOICE_ITEM_UPRICE_MX"];
                                    $amount=$row["INVOICE_ITEM_AMOUNT_MX"];
                                    $serialimei=$row["INVOICE_ITEM_SERIAL_MX"];
                                    $itemdescription=$row["INVOICE_ITEM_DESC_MX"];

    }
```

Ouput 
[image: Ouput]
In Database
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for MYSQL's GROUP_CONCAT() function method. Simply wrap the column name you wish to have returned as a comma separated list with that function like you have used MAX().

[Example:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT student_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(test_score)
FROM student
GROUP BY student_name;
```

This will return, for example,

student_name | test_score
Becky C.     | 80, 77, 95

Note that this value will be truncated according to your db's [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) setting.

Comment: how should i use this ?

Comment: $invoicequery=mysqli_query($link,"Select INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX GROUP_CONCAT(INVOICE_ITEM_SERIAL_MX) from invoice GROUP by INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX ");

Comment: error : Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\memoexpress\admin\createorder\index.php on line 1680